# Find the least upper bounds and the greatest lower bound of $A_2$ = {$\frac{n-1}{n+1}$ $\frac{cos 2n\pi}{3}$ :$ n\in \mathbb{N}$}

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Find  the  least  upper  bounds  and the greatest lower  bound  of $A = \left\{\frac{n-1}{n+1} \cos\left(\frac{ 2n\pi}{3}\right) \mid  n\in \mathbb{N}\right\}$

My Trial  : i take  $n= 1$ , here  i get $A =0$ , for $n=2$, $A=  \frac{1}{4}$,,,,,,,,

Now  im confused how  can i  find the the  least  upper  bounds  and the greatest lower  bound  of $A$.

Any    Hints/ solution  will be  appreciated

Thanks  in advance

Comment: consider the remainder of $n$ when divided by 3, this will give you the way to compute the $cos$.

Comment: Hint: $cos(\frac{2k\pi}{3})$ only takes values as $\{1,-\frac{1}{2}\}$. And $\frac{n-1}{n+1}$ approaches $1$ as $n\to\infty$

Comment: thanks @ Hayk..

Comment: Thanks @ Tamojit,,,,But  im not getting  How $ \frac {n-1}{n+1}$  approaches   1  can u  elaborate more?

Comment: got  it ..thanks,,Tamojits